# CardView in RecyclerView with layout weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 cards I want to display in an activity. I want them both to use 50% of the screen. So it will basically look like two big buttons utilizing the entire screen.

I first used two different CardViews and designed them but I wasn't able to make the OnClickListener work.

So later I made a recyclerview and added these cards through an adapter. However now, the cards don't use the entire screen.

I even tried adding layout weight and keeping the height as 0px to make it work. But that didn't work either.

What can I do now to get what I desire, or is there anything else which I can use instead of a CardView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only two cards and they need to take entire screen, you can use a `LinearLayout` :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

To set click listener:

```
findViewById(R.id.cv_1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I did try this, but wasn't able to make the OnClickListener work. Any pointers there ?

Comment: This worked. I am not sure what went wrong when I tried to add in an OnClickListener. Maybe because I made objects of the CardViews. I'll have to test it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:clickable="true"` to your `CardView` xml attributes to make `OnClickListener` work

Comment: I'll try this and let you know.